# Minecraft performs horribly

Tags: java, kde, minecraft

I recently installed Minecraft on my system. It does work, but it has 10-15 fps on my system. Although on windows it performs better. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

4.0 GB of ram ( 3.7 GB is useable)

AMD A6-6400k apu with radeon HD graphics

Answer (score -2):

1. Try installing Optifine
2. Try giving Minecraft more RAM
3. Try setting the graphics lower.

I won't go into detail how to do all that, google it.

Comment: Sorry i went off-topic, i will try to do this.

Comment: How is it off topic?

Comment: It is a question about Minecraft. The fact that it performs poorly is Mojang's fault, not Ubuntu's.

Comment: Questions about application performance within Ubuntu are on-topic here. ["Questions that you may ask:  ·Running third-party applications on Ubuntu."](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) Fault is irrelevant to topicality.

Comment: oh, i didnt know

Comment: It still peforms badly. Is there a way to fix it still? Can i reduce memory usage? Bedause when i load a world, 99.0% of my memory is shown to be used.

Comment: Well i dont really know anymore... Maybe install Fastcraft?

Comment: This is a perfectly OK answer which got downvoted by noobs anyway. Go figure. If you deleted it, I might post the same answer myself, and if I did I'd probably get away with it. It doesn't seem fair though. I guess these noobs won't believe it until they see screenshots.